# Should I use prepared statements for static values?

Tags: php

Say on each pageload I want to grab the score of one particular use, `SELECT score FROM users WHERE id = 6`. None of those variables will ever change, and I'm not including POST/GET data into it.

Should I still use prepared statements? Or can I just use the `query` function?

Comment: Just hardwire the values - your query cache performance cannot be improved, since the value will not change.

Comment: @halfer, from the field name, it sounds like the value will change. I agree that the information should be cached and updated in the cache instead of hitting the db each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save yourself the trouble and just use query. No need to use prepare statement in that situation, unless taking in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Use query because your inputs are not changing.

Main reason to use prepared statements is to correctly format the arbitrary input that you don't know beforehand.

In my world, using query will give no harm to your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Use Prepared Statement always.

This principle will help you to not think about every new query. Just use prepared statement for it.

Performance? With prepared statement it will be slower(if you do not use one statement for set of data)... ... but this performance difference looks like compare strings performance in single quot and double quot.

P.S. Use constant instead magic number 6.

Answer (score -1):

I've heard that you can get some performance gain from prepared statements. If you have lots of users on your site, you may want to consider using prepared. Otherwise using just a query should be fine.

Lastly, you may also want to consider a way to cache the information. I'm not sure what your program is fully doing, however if you can reduce the number of queries to the db, this can help performance as well.

Comment: No, that "gain" doesn't work this way